# JS delete multiple items from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

So I have a textarea with content, only numbers and | (separators). Example :

```
<textarea>32|11|5|54|</textarea>
```

What I'd like is to append the textarea content, delete only the separators (the |) and keep the numbers, in their order. Get that kind of array :

```
var myArray = [22,9,54,37];
```

*Note that I'm only allowed to basic JS*

---

I know how to get the textarea content in a string, but I don't see how can I push() all the elements in an array, without breaking the numbers (ie having 2,2,9,5,4,3,7 instead of 22,9,54,37) AND deleting the separators. If needed I can change the separator, that's not a problem.

Pre-thanks.

Comment: `new Array('2|11|5|54'.split(/\|/))`

Comment: What constitutes *basic JS*?

Comment: Don't add an answer to your question. If another answer answered your question, then accept it. If you want to add your own answer, then add it.

Comment: @torazaburo thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the split() function in javascript, and pass it the `|` as a parameter. This will create an array that contains all the numbers in order, without the | symbol.

If you need the numbers in order, then you can use the .join() with `,` passed in to create a string for output.

Javascript:

```
var textarea = document.getElementById( "textarea" ).value;
var values = textarea.split('|');
var valuesAsString = values.join(', ');
```

HTML:

```
<textarea id="textarea">32|11|5|14</textarea>
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought split() would still add the specified separator between every elements, and just didn't know it wouldn't add it if it was already there. Problem solved !

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

> Use `split` to split the string based on the `separator`.

Use `.filter` to remove `empty` values

Use `.map` to cast string to Number

Try this:

```js
var val = document.getElementById('ta').value;
var arr = val.split('|').filter(function(item) {
  return item; //empty string is falsey value
}).map(Number); // cast string to Number
console.log(arr);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<textarea id='ta'>32|11|5|54|</textarea>
```

Comment: this fails with empty value in betwee. try this `32|11| |5|54|`

Comment: Yeah. Let's go get sushi and not pay. Did you consider `val.split('|').filter(String).map(Number)`?

Comment: @Seb, That was too much mate...:P Enjoyed it ;)

Comment: You could also use `String.trim` instead, to address the above issue: `val.split('|').filter(String.trim).map(Number)`

Comment: @Seb, You are making everyone happy here... :)

Comment: ... and one final trick along these lines: `val.split('|').filter(String.trim).filter(isFinite).map(Number)` to remove anything that's `NaN`. Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

use trim in filter condition to check empty values.

try this

```js
var res = '32|11|5|54|'.split('|').filter(function(v) {
  return v.trim() != ''
})
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + '</pre>')

res = '32|11||5|54|'.split('|').filter(function(v) {
  return v.trim() != ''
})
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + '</pre>')

res = '32|11| |5|54|'.split('|').filter(function(v) {
  return v.trim() != ''
})
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + '</pre>')
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the `String.prototype.split` method which accepts separator as an argument. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

So in your case it will be `'22|33|44'.split('|')`

If you want add these values to an existing array, you should use `Array.prototype.conat` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat